# Including a specific value restriction in regular expression validator

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'd like to include a restriction to my regex below, so that `name`, `NAME`, `Name`, `NaMe`, etc. could not pass validation with the following REV:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbAttColName"
                    CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Column can only contain alpha numeric and spaces, and must start with a letter"
                    ValidationGroup="AddColumn" Text="*" ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z ]*$" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Examples of valid input:

```
nam
nam1
name1
theName
N1ame
helloname
whatisyourname
```

Examples of invalid input:

```
1name
Name
NAME
NaMe
naME
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info on what can and can't be accepted? To look for name regardless of case: `[Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]`

Comment: is `nam` is a valid input ? and provide some valid inputs

Comment: The regex I posted does not allow a string containing `Name`, what do you need then?

Comment: If you do not want to allow a whole string `Name`,  use `^(?![Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$`

Comment: Or this: `^(?!(?:[Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]|.[Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]))[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$`

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by *include the word into regex*? Best with some sample strings.

Comment: So, what worked for you? Your question needs editing to make it clear and answerable.

Comment: but unfortunately these examples have not worked. So I have my existing validationExpression="^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z ]*$" to this I want to add the word name (include both casing) so for example the user can add an attribute as nam or namer but cant add it as name

Comment: In what way did my last example not work? Causes error? Lets name be inputed? As @WiktorStribiżew said, give us a few test cases in your question.

Comment: ok so @Neal you example of ^(?!(?:[Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]|.[Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]))[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-‌​9 ]*$ came closest. For this I can add 'nam' but cant add 'name1'. I only want the validation to fire if the only text that is entered is name

Comment: as in all these should pass...nam, nam1, name1, 1name, theName, N1ame, helloname, whatisyourname etc.... only the single word name will fail, as well as my existing rule ^[[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z ]*$

Comment: See [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hqOYYn/2), it works exactly as you described, does not allow a whole `name` string only. BTW, `1name` cannot match since it does not start with a letter.

Comment: That means the issue is out there. Are you binding to the correct element? Check `ControlToValidate="tbAttColName"`

Comment: Yeah was binding it to the correct control...Your last example was a fix for it thank you for he help folks. If you want to write up the answer I can tick it, thanks again @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to allow any value meeting your pattern *excluding* a certain value (that is equal to the full string). It means you need to add a negative lookahead anchored at the start and its pattern should be anchored at the end of string with `$`.

```
^(?![Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hqOYYn/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]$)` - the whole string cannot equal a `name` string (case insensitive)
- `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[A-Za-z0-9 ]*` - zero or more ASCII letter, digits or spaces
- `$` - end of string.